# Simplest example - how to parse html with saxon using java?

Tags: java, saxon

Could anyone say, why the following code does not give any results?
Of course html is valid and has a lot of "div" elements.

```
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    proc.setConfigurationProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/sourceParserClass", "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
    XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();

    DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
    XdmNode doc = builder.build(new File("/tmp/test.html"));

    XPathSelector selector = xpath.compile("//div").load();
    selector.setContextItem(doc);

    for (XdmItem item : selector)
    {
        System.out.println(((XdmNode)item).getNodeName());
    }
```

I took that code from saxon samples and added "proc.setConfigurationProperty..." in order to parse html input.

All i want is:
1) submit html string
2) get document node
3) make some queries with xpath v3

Thank you.
P.s. I don't want to use xslt.

Comment: A minor comment, rather than setting the HTML parser as a global option for the whole application, I would do `builder.build(new SAXSource(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser(), new InputSource("/tmp/test.html")))`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "//div" to "//*[name()="div"]" solved the problem.

Comment: That reveals the problem: the elements are in a namespace. (Search SO for "XPath default namespace" and you will find hundreds of hits.) But your solution is wrong, because your code now depends on the choice of namespace prefix. You should either use //*:div to match div elements in any namespace (or none), or use //div having first done xpath.declareNamespace("", XHTML_NS) to ensure that unprefixed names refer to elements in the XHTML namespace.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for your comments, very helpful.
Question about namespace: i tried to set namespace via "xpath.declareNamespace("", XHTML_NS)" but there is no such constant XHTML_NS.
how can that be possible?)

Comment: Sorry, I was using a shortcut to save myself typing. You will have to declare the constant yourself, or use the literal value `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.